# How to upload to google drive with service account and php

Tags: php, google-drive-api, service-accounts

Down you can see my code and it uploads files to my google drive. Now I am trying to use service account to let the people to upload files to my Google drive without their google accounts (Visitors will submit html form with their file and my app will upload that file to my drive ). But I am stuck with it. Can not find even just one working example. Any ideas?

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE);
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);

    // store in the session also
    $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;

    // redirect back to the example
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    }
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
echo $client->getAccessToken();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && $client->getAccessToken()) {
    // We'll setup an empty 1MB file to upload.
    DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'test.jpg');
    if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
        $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
        fseek($fh, 1024 * 1024);
        fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
    $file = new Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $file->setName("Hello World!");
    $result = $service->files->create(
        $file,
        [
            'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
            'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        ]
    );
    $permissionService = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $permissionService->role = "reader";
    $permissionService->type = "anyone"; // anyone with the link can view the file
    $service->permissions->create($result->id, $permissionService);
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you have now? besides the fact that it doesn't look like service account authorization code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Nothings Wrong. I just need to rewrite this code to make it work with service account. I cant find anything. Its my first time working on Google Drive API and everything so hard for me

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show you how to set up service account authorization.

Remember though the files will be uploaded to the service accounts drive account. If you want them uploaded to your personal drive account. You need to share a directory on your drive account with the service account.  You do that though the web app like you would any other user, using the service account email address.  Its the property that looks like an email.

You should just be able to remove the auth you have now and then use this.  You will however need set the parents in the upload metadata to be that of that directory you want the fill uploaded to.

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');


/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed. 
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::DRIVE)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {   
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(array(Google_Service_Analytics::DRIVE));
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Doing something like this  will then get you the same service object.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive(getGoogleClient());
```