# Uploading to google drive with service account generate error

Tags: php, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm tring to use this code to upload file from server to gdrive using service account. I created project, service account, downloaded json, created shared folder and inserted service account email for shared folder.

but this code generate error:

> Argument #2 ($request) must be of type
> Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile
> given

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
include_once 'templates/base.php';

// Use the developers console and download your service account
// credentials in JSON format. Place the file in this directory or
// change the key file location if necessary.
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/service-account.json');

/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    return getServiceAccountClient();
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * array(Google_Service_Analytics::DRIVE)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getServiceAccountClient() {
    try {
        // Create and configure a new client object.
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
        return $client;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}


/*************************************************
 * Ensure you've downloaded your oauth credentials
 ************************************************/
if (!$oauth_credentials = getOAuthCredentialsFile()) {
    echo missingOAuth2CredentialsWarning();
    return;
}

/************************************************
 * The redirect URI is to the current page, e.g:
 * http://localhost:8080/large-file-upload.php
 ************************************************/
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
//$service = new Google\Service\Drive($client);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive(getGoogleClient());

// add "?logout" to the URL to remove a token from the session
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}

/************************************************
 * If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
 * we need to exchange that with the
 * Google\Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
 * function. We store the resultant access token
 * bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);

    // store in the session also
    $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;

    // redirect back to the example
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

// set the access token as part of the client
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
    }
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
 * If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
 * file.
 ************************************************/
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    /************************************************
     * We'll setup an empty 20MB file to upload.
     ************************************************/
    //DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile.txt');
    DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'test.jpg');
    if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
        $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
        fseek($fh, 1024*1024*20);
        fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    $file = new Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
    $file->name = "Big File";
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $request = $service->files->create($file);

    // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
    $media = new Google\Http\MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $request,
        'image/jpg',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));

    // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
    // complete.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        // read until you get $chunkSizeBytes from TESTFILE
        // fread will never return more than 8192 bytes if the stream is read
        // buffered and it does not represent a plain file
        // An example of a read buffered file is when reading from a URL
        $chunk = readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
    // that has been uploaded.
    $result = false;
    if ($status != false) {
        $result = $status;
    }

    fclose($handle);

}

function readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSize)
{
    $byteCount = 0;
    $giantChunk = "";
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        // fread will never return more than 8192 bytes if the stream is read
        // buffered and it does not represent a plain file
        $chunk = fread($handle, 8192);
        $byteCount += strlen($chunk);
        $giantChunk .= $chunk;
        if ($byteCount >= $chunkSize) {
            return $giantChunk;
        }
    }
    return $giantChunk;
}
?>

    <div class="box">
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Click here to upload" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'd like to find file uploaded to the shared folder

Comment: Please confirm which of these many lines of code is throwing the error. At a guess, maybe the `$media = new Google\Http\MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $request,
        'image/jpg',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );` line?

Comment: As we can see at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/src/Http/MediaFileUpload.php and from the error message, the constructor expects an instance of `RequestInterface` as the second argument, but you've supplied a `DriveFile` instead. Did you get this code from a tutorial, or did you write it yourself?

Comment: yes, second parameter ($request) has wrong type. I used code from here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/large-file-upload.php and from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558510/how-to-upload-to-google-drive-with-service-account-and-php#_=_ (i used answer code)

Comment: I did it! problem was missing folder name!

    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        //Set the Random Filename
        'name' => "test file",
        //Set the Parent Folder
        'parents' => array('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') // this is the folder id
    ));