# Resumable Upload to google drive with service account error

Tags: php, file-upload, google-drive-api

Currently trying to do a resumable upload to google drive api with PHP but an error is created "Expected type 'Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface'. Found 'Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile'". Here is my code:

```
$client = new \Google\Client();
 $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
 $driveService = new Google\Service\Drive($client);
 $file = new Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
 $file->setName($filename);
 $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
 $client->setDefer(true);
 $request = $driveService->files->create(
  $file,
  [
  'data' => file_get_contents($filepath),
  'uploadType' => 'resumable'
  ]
 );



// ERROR
 $chunkSizeBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
 $media = new Google\Http\MediaFileUpload(
  $client,
  $request,
  'text/csv',
  null,
  true,
  $chunkSizeBytes
 );
```

The error is while passing $request in MediaFileUpload.
Thanks

Comment: $request must be an object that implements the Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface. Google\Service\Drive does not seem to implement the Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface. Guzzle has implemented this interface.

Comment: My solution was implemented from the oficial document https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/large-file-upload.php. How can i implement this RequestInterface here?

Answer (score 2):

From your example:

```php
$driveService = new Google\Service\Drive($client);
// [...]
$client->setDefer(true);
// [...]
```

In my opinion, `$client->setDefer(true)` is set too late. Also in the Google example. In my opinion, [the line is therefore always false](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/c73bdc5734425455f748c134b53598a34e9a4735/src/Service/Resource.php#L230). If it is true, the return should be RequestInterface.

Therefore I would try the following. I don't have GoogleDrive, which is why I can't test it.

```php
$client->setDefer(true);
$driveService = new Google\Service\Drive($client);
```

**Update:**

I was already interested in this yesterday and had tried something again yesterday.

In the following example, $request is from type RequestInterface. Yesterday I also tried to generate auth data on Google. But somehow an auth error keeps coming up. I'm sure I'm missing something. The auth error occurs when I set `$client->setDefer(false);`.

```php
$client = new Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . "/oauth-credentials.json");
$client->setDefer(true);
$driveService = new Google\Service\Drive($client);
$file = new DriveFile();
$file->setName('test.txt');

$request = $driveService->files->create(
    $file,
    [
        'data' => file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/test.txt"),
        'uploadType' => 'resumable'
    ]
);

$this->assertInstanceOf(RequestInterface::class, $request);
```

I think, this is an issue in the GoogleAPI package. The example is already faulty. The error is also displayed in the IDE. Not everything Google does is perfect.

*large-file-upload.php*
[image]

Here is a discussion on Stackoverflow in March 2023:
[Uploading to google drive with service account generate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767076/uploading-to-google-drive-with-service-account-generate-error)

An open ticket from July 2019 which appears to have been closed without resolution:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1680

Or this open issue:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1881

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work still. Seems that $request isn't returning a RequestInterface as expected.

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: After all the research, I haven't found a solution to the problem yet.