# How to add content to a file using the Google Drive API in PHP?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to upload a large file that is over 10 gigabytes in size to Google Drive. With the help of Google I wrote the following code:

```
public function upload($pathToFile) {
    $client = $this->client;
    $service = $this->drive;

    $fname = basename($pathToFile);
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile([
        'name' => $fname,
    ]);
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 200;

    $request = $service->files->create($file);
    $fileId = $request->id;

    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $request,
        'text/plain',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($pathToFile));

    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($pathToFile, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    return $status != false;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Google\Http\MediaFileUpload::__construct() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, instance of Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile given, called
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems you're not the only person having issues regarding this - [**see here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76739898/2518525). A few people are using `$client->setDefer(true);` prior to specifying  their `$file` - maybe that could help you?

Comment: um, just reading the error here and not getting too deep into it... He seems to be passing the incorrect instance DriveFile, when the variable $request should be RequestInterface which probably means an error.

Comment: But you are creating a file on google drive to upload a file to google drive?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create doesn't seem or sound right. look at the documentation create should return an instance of File. which you are setting as the request....

Comment: @amac, what method can be used instead of create?

Comment: @Darren, can you give an example of how to upload a large file in parts?

Comment: @user153742 - I haven't dealt with Googles API's in a long time, but a quick search warranted [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/large-file-upload.php) example in their github repo - may be of use to you

Comment: Alright, I actually dug into their github repo. What version are you using @user153742? Supposedly they fixed this issue. https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/pull/2274

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed for version v2.12.6. This is the pull request confirming that https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v2.12.6

From the previous versions at some point this line was changed and caused a side effect error. According to their repository. So OP you were correct on the create. Google has so many ways of doing the same thing I misspoke without looking too deep.

```
        $response = $this->client->execute($this->request, null);
        $response = $this->client->execute($this->request, false);
```

The laid out example of how to implement this in a way that was confirmed to work is as so:

```
        $gfmeta = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $gfmeta->name = $backupFileName;
        $gfmeta->parents = array($GoogleDriveBackupParentFolderID);
        $backupFilePath = dirname(__FILE__) . "/".$backupFileName;

        // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
        $GoogleClient->setDefer(TRUE);
        $guploadRequest = $GoogleDriveApp->files->create($gfmeta);

        // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process
        $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $GoogleClient,
            $guploadRequest,
            mime_content_type($backupFilePath),
            NULL,
            TRUE,
            $GoogleDriveUploadChunkSizeBytes
        );
        $media->setFileSize(filesize($backupFilePath));
        
        // Upload the various chunks. $uploadStreamStatus will be false until complete
        $uploadStreamStatus = FALSE;
        $backupFileHandle = fopen($backupFilePath, "rb");
        while(!$uploadStreamStatus && !feof($backupFileHandle)) {
            $fileChunk = readFileChunk($backupFileHandle, $GoogleDriveUploadChunkSizeBytes);
            $uploadStreamStatus = $media->nextChunk($fileChunk);
        }
        // Take care of the file handle and file creation in Google
        $GoogleClient->setDefer(FALSE);
        fclose($backupFileHandle);

        // The final value of $uploadStreamStatus will be the data from the API for the upload
        $result = FALSE;
        if($uploadStreamStatus !== FALSE) {
                $result = $uploadStreamStatus;
        } else {
        #       throw new Exception("Upload Error!");
        }
```

I believe that if you use this version with a like structure of code process it should work.